# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'concat'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I split the data I have and processed it, I need to reunite it to train the model, but the **'DataFrame' object has no attribute**, I get a 'concat' error. I checked the versions. Everything is like normal.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
import numpy as np

#Verilerin Yüklenmesi
pd=pd.read_csv('data.csv')

city=pd.iloc[:,5].values
color=pd.iloc[:,3].values
km=pd.iloc[:,2].values
year=pd.iloc[:,1].values
model=pd.iloc[:,0].values

digest=[]
for i in range(565):
    # Regular Expression (Yorumlardaki noktalama işaretlerini değiştirme)
    comment=re.sub('[A-Z]','',pd['fiyat'][i])
    # Lower (Küçük harfe çevirme)
    comment=comment.lower()
    # Split (Kelimeleri listeye çevirme)
    comment=comment.split()
    # Stopword al kümeye çevir kümelerinde içinde kelime yoksa gövdesini bul 
    comment=' '.join(comment)
    digest.append(comment)
    
#Toplam eksik hücre sayısı
total=pd.isnull().sum()

#Encoder Nomimal Ordinal->Number
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le=LabelEncoder()
city=le.fit_transform(city)
color=le.fit_transform(color)
model=le.fit_transform(model)

#dataframe dönüştürme İşlemi
from pandas import DataFrame

model=DataFrame(data=model,columns=['model'])
year=DataFrame(data=year,columns=['year'])
km=DataFrame(data=km,columns=['km'])
color=DataFrame(data=color,columns=['color'])
city=DataFrame(data=city,columns=['city'])
price = DataFrame (data=digest,columns=['price'])

frames = [color, city]
#Birleştirme İşlemi
s1=pd.concat(model,year,axis=1)
```

Error

[image]

Comment: Please include the output error as well.

Comment: The image you provided shows a different error than the `AttributeError` for `concat` you mention in the first sentence. The error from the image indicates that you again reassigned the name `pd` to a DataFrame and then try to call the non-existing method `read_csv`. This is however not happening in the code you posted. There is only one call to `read_csv`, and at that point `pd` still points to the `pandas` module. Voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`concat` is an attribute of `pandas`, which you imported as `pd`.

In the line

```
pd=pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

you reassign the name `pd`. It is now a DataFrame. DataFrames don't have an attribute `concat`.

Comment: I tried but there was no solution again I get the same error

Comment: @EmreŞimşek What did you try? As it stands your erroneous reassignment of the name `pd` is everything we can point out, your question lacks debugging details if there are further errors.

Comment: @EmreŞimşek the image you provided shows a different error than the error you mention in the first sentence. The error indicates that you again reassigned the name `pd` to a DataFrame and then try to call the non-existing method `read_csv`. This is however not happening in the code you posted. There is only one call to `read_csv`, and at that point `pd` still points to the `pandas` module. Voted to close.

Comment: how i overlooked Thank you very much, the problem is fixed